# How to change the default y axis for self stack bar

Tags: c#, teechart

I want to plot a Bar series with MultiBars style as SelfStack. By default the self stack bar y axis value is 0 , Is there any way to change the default y axis for self stack bar

- public class Bar_SelfStack 
         {
             private Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar bar1;
             private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
             private Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1;
             private Steema.TeeChart.Tools.GridBand gridBand1;

  ```
         public Bar_SelfStack()
         {
             // This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
             InitializeComponent();

             bar1.Add(100, "Cars");
             bar1.Add(300, "Phones");
             bar1.Add(200, "Lamps");

             // Set "Self-Stacked":
             bar1.MultiBar = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.MultiBars.SelfStack;

             // cosmetic
             bar1.Marks.Visible = false;
             bar1.Marks.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.MarksStyles.Value;
             bar1.ColorEach = true;
         }
     }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default Y axis to custom vertical axis as do in next simple code:

```
Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1; 
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    tChart1 = new TChart();
    this.Controls.Add(tChart1);
    tChart1.Top = 150;
    tChart1.Left = 100;
    tChart1.Height = 400;
    tChart1.Width = 550; 
    InitializeChart();
}
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar series1, series2, series3,series4;
Steema.TeeChart.Axis axis1; 

private void InitializeChart()
{
    tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false; 
    series1 = new Bar(tChart1.Chart);
    series2 = new Bar(tChart1.Chart);
    series3 = new Bar(tChart1.Chart);
    series4 = new Bar(tChart1.Chart); 
    axis1 = new Axis(tChart1.Chart);  
    tChart1.Axes.Custom.Add(axis1); 
    series1.FillSampleValues();
    series2.FillSampleValues();
    series3.FillSampleValues(); 
    series4.FillSampleValues();
    series1.Marks.Visible = false;
    series2.Marks.Visible = false;
    series3.Marks.Visible = false;
    series4.Marks.Visible = false; 
    axis1.RelativePosition = tChart1.Panel.MarginLeft -12;
    tChart1.Panel.MarginLeft = 10; 
    axis1.Horizontal = false;
    series1.CustomVertAxis = axis1;
    series1.MultiBar = MultiBars.SelfStack;
    button1.Click +=button1_Click;
}
```

Could you tell us if previous code help you to achieve as you want?

I hope will helps.

Thanks,

Comment: Please see the edits , What i want to achieve is "Cars" data should start from new Y location (Say 10) instead of 0 so the final series will be like 10-110 (Cars) , 110-410 (Phones) , 410-600 (Lamps) w.r.t y axis